# How to set custom ringtone for contacts group in Lollipop contact app

Tags: contacts, 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g, ringtone, contact-groups

I'm using Moto g with Lollipop 5.0.2. I can add contacts to group by edit contact.

1. How do I add specific ringtone for specific contact?
2. How do I add specific ringtone for specific group?
3. If there are no options, where do I give feedback for these options?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible in stock Android to set a specific ringtone for an entire Circle. You can however, edit a specific contact and in the edit menu you can set a custom Ringtone.

[image: Sample Image]

If this is not what you want then you can send Google Feedback any time.

Comment: Thank you, But I can't see any feedback link in contacts app.

Answer (score 1):

> 2. How do I add specific ringtone for specific group?

You can use the app **[Group Ringtones](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appventive.groupring&hl=en)** to do it.

**Steps**:
1. Make sure a group is created in your default Contacts/Phone app (available while creating a new contact) and contacts are added to it.
2. Open that app, and select ringtone for each group.

> 1. How do I add specific ringtone for specific contact?

For this, you can do as @lokmamcetin said

Comment: As of August 2018, I get a "not found" error when I click on the above link.  Maybe the app has been retired?

Answer (score 0):

All below is right, but my problem was, that after contacts transfer from my old Android, in the contact edition menu the groups are present, but in the contacts main menu - groups menu item not exists... 
The problem was solved by creation of a new group on the new device (Android 6.01) - then immediately appears "Groups" in the contacts menu, and there were also appears imported groups. That's when you CAN change the melody for each group of contacts: colleagues will call you a certain music - whatever you choose from ringtones or local music files what you own.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need an app to set per-group ringtones.  It seems like Android only supports per-contact ringtones, so most of the group ringtone apps simply automatically set all the per-contact ringtones for you.

Search on the Google Play App Store for: "[group ringtone](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=group%20ringtone&c=apps)"

I use the [Group Ringtone Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.insadco.groupringtonelite) app.

Answer (score -1):

Try the app: **[DW Contacts & Phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dw.contacts.free&hl=en)**

1. **Open** the app and select the '**Toolbox**' tab.
2. Click on "**Groups**". Now select any standard group or create a New group from Options(3dots at top right).
3. Add required contacts to that group. Then select **Options->Set Ringtone for shown contacts** inside that group to set ringtone for that particular group (or set of contacts)

Comment: Can you link this and explain how to use it?